# append coordinates on to a div when clicked on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when ever i hover over the image coordinates are displayed i would like to append those coordinates in a div is it possible

here is a fiddle of what i have so far 
[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/kunz/kuvL4qm4/)

**Jquery.js**

```
  $('.hover').mousemove(function(e){

        var hovertext = $('.hover').attr('hovertext');
        $('#hoverdiv').text('(' + e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY + ')').show();
        $('#hoverdiv').css('top',e.clientY).css('left',e.clientX);

    }).$('#img').on('click', function () {
    $('(' + e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY + ')').appendTo('#append');
  }) .mouseout(function(){
        $('#hoverdiv').hide();
    });
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="hoverdiv"></div>
<img id="img" class="hover" src="Coordinates.svg.png"  hovertext="" />

<div id="append">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated your code a little bit and I hope it fulfills your requirements.

```js
$('.hover').mousemove(function(e) {

  var hovertext = $('.hover').attr('hovertext');
  $('#hoverdiv').text('(' + e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY + ')').show();
  $('#hoverdiv').css('top', e.clientY).css('left', e.clientX);

}).mouseout(function() {
  $('#hoverdiv').hide();
});

$('#img').click(function(e) {
  $('#append').append('(' + e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY + ')');
});
```

```css
#hoverdiv {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #404040;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="img" class="hover" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/2D_Cartesian_Coordinates.svg/376px-2D_Cartesian_Coordinates.svg.png" hovertext="" />

<div id="append">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code to capture the coordinates on `hover` and `click`.

To append text to a div on hover, add `$('#append').append('(' + e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY + ')');` to your `mousemove` event.

**Note:** I have added an offset of 10px to the `hoverDiv` to move it away from cursor.

[Updated Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/kuvL4qm4/5/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.hover').mousemove(function(e) {
    var hovertext = $('.hover').attr('hovertext');
    $('#hoverdiv').text('(' + e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY + ')').show();
    $('#hoverdiv').css('top', e.clientY).css('left', e.clientX + 10);
    $('#appendHover').append('(' + e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY + ')');
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $('#hoverdiv').hide();
  });
  $('.hover').click(function(e) {
    $('#appendClick').append('(' + e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY + ')');
  });
});
```

```css
#hoverdiv {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #404040;
  padding: 7px;
}
#appendClick {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
#appendHover {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hoverdiv"></div>
<img id="img" class="hover" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/2D_Cartesian_Coordinates.svg/376px-2D_Cartesian_Coordinates.svg.png" hovertext="" />

<div id="appendClick">
</div>
<div id="appendHover">
</div>
```

Comment: kool but i need a onclick event how would i do that

Answer (score 0):

Try a click event like this and see if it helps:

```
$('#img').click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    alert(e.pageX - offset.left);
    alert(e.pageY - offset.top);
  });
```

If it's ok you can just append it to a div.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the click event won't call because the mouse will be constantly over `#hoverdiv` instead. So you will want to add a click event to that:

```
$('#hoverdiv').on('click', function (e) {
    $( '<span>(' + e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY + ')</span>' ).appendTo( "#append" );
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('#hoverdiv').hide();
});
```

Also note the `appendTo()` functions needs a [*html string*](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString) as the argument. So add some tags (such as `<span>`).

[**Demo**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/kuvL4qm4/4/)

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in the code.

1. The binding of click event to the image was not done correctly.
2. The tooltip displayed was right below the mouse and therefore the click event of the image was not going through. Please add and offset left or top so that the tooltip doesnt interfere with the click on the image.
3. I guess appendTo expects html and not plain text.

Corrected Code

```
 $('.hover').mousemove(function(e){
    var hovertext = $('.hover').attr('hovertext');
    $('#hoverdiv').text('(' + e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY + ')').show();
    $('#hoverdiv').css('top',e.clientY).css('left',e.clientX + 10);
   }).on('click', function (e) {
      $('<p>(' + e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY + ')</p>').appendTo('#append');
   }) .mouseout(function(){
      $('#hoverdiv').hide();
  });
```